How can I identify the key of a piece I'm composing?
When I want to start a new composition, I never know how to determine the key, so I often end up with something that looks like this: No key signature, and lots of accidentals. How do I choose a key?
Here's a picture of something I'm working on that illustrates the problem.


This question isn't quite what I expected from the title. Essentially, you have a key, and are looking to identify it. A different question would be, if a piece can be "transposed" to any given key by moving the notes up or down... how does a composer decide where to settle it?

This question is similar to: When is a piece in A minor versus C major?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AndyBonner Heh, guess it's easier for a songwriter than a composer: The key isn't an integral part of the piece anyway, feel free to transpose as suits your voice range or instrument. The key I write it down in is just the key in which I play it.

@Divizna Oh, it can be integral. That wasn't the question asked, but there's plenty to discuss about instrument voicings as well as human range, extra-musical connotation, temperaments, etc.

Actually, I think better answers for "how do you identify the key of a selection" are in "D major with no C tone."

I’m voting to close this question because the question is either "how do I determine the key of some composition", in which case there are duplicate questions as indicated in the comments, or "in what key is this piece I wrote", which is not the kind of asker-specific question we answer here.

I don't think you are explaining enough about your understanding of keys and key signatures. If someone were to say this excerpt is nominally in E flat minor would you be able to agree/disagree why? If you can't, and you want to be able to do that, the problem is not about composition and choosing keys. It's a matter of getting a basic foundation in major/minor keys and tonal harmony.

@MichaelCurtis thank you! do you have resources you'd recommend for me to learn more about those concepts please?

@oluwatomilola, on the theory side you want a college textbook on harmony like Walter Piston's Harmony or Kostka/Payne Tonal Harmony. On the practice side, for piano, you would play scales and cadences in all major and minor keys.

If your problem is to actually CHOOSE a key, then that must happen before you write any notes at all. And you choose a key according to taste: how high or low do you want your melody to be, what chord fingerings do you want to use if you're a guitarist, how many flats or sharps you like to have. But you said you already wrote some notes, so you're not CHOOSING a key at all here.
If your song already has a tonic i.e. key, but you cannot IDENTIFY what that tonic is, then the question is just "how to tell what key a song is in." And the only difference to all the other "how to tell what key a song is in" questions is, it's your own song.
That question has been asked many times before. There are some rules of thumb to identify potential, candidate keys, such as looking at the last note or what notes are used the most, are they sharp or flat, etc. In my opinion, the best way to tell what key a song is in, is to learn to play melodies and harmony by ear, and to learn what a tonic feels like.
EDIT: I don't think this applies to the OP's concrete case, but for completeness, I'll add that sometimes, a melody can be re-harmonized to a different key, by using backing instruments. Which would be a "choosing a key for existing notes" kind of scenario. In other words, the question would be: what key could I make this be by re-harmonizing it. For example a melody that by itself would more naturally be identified as being in A minor, might sometimes be re-harmonizable to be in D minor, perhaps using the D Dorian mode (Dorian is a minor mode, so the key would still be called D minor even if it's Dorian). This changes the harmonic interpretation or "meaning" of the melody, as the perceived pitches relative to the tonic are different. What used to be tonic chord notes A, C, E for an A minor tonic, can be interpreted as creating an upper structure triad of a Dm9 chord, against a suitable backing chord. Whether or not a believable D minor key is created, is up to the arranger's skills. This can be a relevant scenario not only in jazz, but when using pre-recorded vocal melody samples in electronic dance music, hip-hop and whatever.

I think, yes, this question is about actually analyzing the excerpt to identify the tonic. Can you help identify a duplicate to close with? I haven't found a great one, but I'll vote with my best finding.

Sounds like OP simply chooses notes to make up a song, and then wants to have a way to identify the key. It's preferable, but not necessary, to have a key in mind initially, but some folk just don't (or can't) work that way.

@AndyBonner I didn't say this should be closed. You know, I actually answered the question and didn't write a close request comment.  What I'm saying is, the question "how to find the key of a song when I wrote the song myself" should be treated no differently from just "how to find the key of a song". And that would be the solution of this question. The relevant thing to understand is: it doesn't matter who wrote it.

@Tim yeah that's the situation here, but piiperi's answer really helps put things into perspective for me. Thank you

Two criteria initially. One, decide what note 'feels at rest in the piece - often the last note/chord of the song, one that keeps being returned to, as if it's 'home'.
Then make a list of all those 'accidentals' - as that's what they are at present. Start with B♭, then E♭, A♭, D♭ in that order, until you've found them all.
There's a good possibility that the corresponding number of flats will give the answer to what key you're in. For example, if there are 3 flats only in the piece, then it's most likely in key E♭, which should match 'home'.
If you hear an accidental note that sounds like it's gone out of key, it may well have done, and that stays as an accidental, rather than being counted - generally if it occurs only a very few times.

I'd specifically say this passage is in E flat minor, as it has G flats but no G naturals.

@Tim Really? G minor? Is it possible you're mistaking a clef somewhere? That seems like a very odd choice. And yes, I think that's exactly the OP's objective: They've written a very tonal piece and are wondering how they can determine which key they've in fact used.

Definitely Eb minor. The bass establishes Eb as tonic and first melody note is a Gb that is not a leading tone but instead descends to Eb.

@oluwatomilola Agree with JohnBelzaguy and Dekkadeci.  2nd measure bass line is Eb melodic minor scale going up, while the 4th measure Voice gives us the first 3 scale degrees of Eb minor.  So the key signature is 6 flats and then you need to put naturals accordingly (see E flat melodic minor scale).
